# Can't use Excel while code is running

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I was trying go gather/scrape data from the Web using this code:

```
Sub GetSP()
Dim appIE As Object

Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "http://uk.investing.com/currencies/streaming-forex-rates-majors"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

RunCodeEveryX:

Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementById("pair_1")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(2).innerHTML
Range("A1").Value = myValue

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
GoTo RunCodeEveryX

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

However, when the code is running, I can't even edit the Excel because Excel seems to be busy working on getting the data. What I hope for was the code is running, I can do something out of the same sheet with the web scraping continuing.

Is there any alternative to wait now? (Which I think makes Excel busy)

Thanks!

@jeeped - I was able to gather the appropriate data using your preferred mode and successfully extract the data. I wonder if there is a good way to repeat this step infinitely (since the data is refreshing on the webpage, I'd like this to repeat as with my initial code) until I stop it while being able to edit the rest of the worksheet.

Thanks! Hope you don't mind me addressing you specifically though the question is open to everyone.

```
Sub GetSP()

Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim oHttp As MSXML2.xmlHTTP


On Error Resume Next
Set oHttp = New MSXML2.xmlHTTP
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")
    MsgBox "Error 0 has occured"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
If oHttp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Just cannot make"
    Exit Sub
End If

oHttp.Open "GET", "http://uk.investing.com/currencies/streaming-forex-rates-majors", False
oHttp.send
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText

With HTMLDoc
    PriceGetter = .getElementById("pair_1").innerText
    PriceGetter2 = .getElementsByClassName("pid-1-bid")(0).innerText
    Range("A1").Value = PriceGetter
    Range("A2").Value = PriceGetter2
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA should be considered primarily single threaded. You are only asking for trouble. Move away from an InternetExplorer application in favor of an xmlhttprequest to speed up your retrievals.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped I'd love to learn and read about it. Would it work with Excel, too?

Comment: See [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4039065+%5Bexcel%5Dxmlhttp). Those are just mine; there are many more.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped looks good especially the NASA one. I'm reading your suggestions.

Comment: @Jeeped hope you can take a look. I was successful in getting the data but repeating the process infinitely as if streaming the data - I'm still stuck with suggestions below or my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Loop instead of the `Application.Wait`. When you are using `DoEvents` inside it, the App is still responsive.

If you are on Windows, here is a Function that sleeps for a certain amount of time:

```
Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Function Sleep(milliseconds As Long)


Dim NowTick As Long
Dim EndTick As Long

EndTick = GetTickCount + (milliseconds)

Do
    NowTick = GetTickCount
    DoEvents
Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
Sleep 1000 'Sleeps for 1 Second
```

Comment: The code works very well! I'm not sure though if I placed it correctly. My original code is in Sheet1, the function you shared, I put it in Module1 (I created a module). So it works well, but the problem is, whenever I type something on the sheet, it throws an error 400.

Comment: Or `Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`

Comment: @bebongtheshark Error 400 is a bad request, check your URL

Comment: @OliverCarr The Sleep from kernel32 makes the app unresponsive as well

Comment: Hi @OliverCarr I'm not changing any urls from the original code. While the code is supposed to be running on the background, the code interrupt when I edit a cell and then hits a 400.

Comment: @bebongtheshark are you sure this error is not coming from your code? Since you weren't able to actually test yours with the Application.Wait

Comment: Hi @gizlmeier I encountered the error only when I replaced my Application.Wait code. Not sure how this happened.